# Segue Between View Controllers based on Condition

Tags: ios, swift

I am a new iOS developer and I'm writing an application that involves user login. Essentially, I would like to set the next view that the user sees based on a condition from the backend.(The conditional portion of this problem has already been solved, I successfully received the data through an Alamofire http get request)

My question is that, if I want to segue from one view controller to another, does it have to be sequential? I created two segues from the initial view controller to the two separate view controllers. However, if I try to segue to the view controller (that is not sequentially after) I receive the following error:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What would be the proper way to implement what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can't segue to a view controller that is not sequentially after , better way to solve your problem is to embed the initial VC inside a navigationController whenever you want to load any view controller ,  you can do this

```
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "anotherView")
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

where identifier is the storyboardID of the VC you want to show in above case it's **anotherView**
Here is where you set it

[image]

Comment: I actually tried this method, however, it didn't work.   if (hasRegistered == true){
                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainScreen")
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
                    }

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand much English, but I think it means that you want to change the view sequence and the rootController.

When the user is not logged in, the rootController will be the one marked as initial.

After login, we need to change the rootController to the new view sequence by starting the first controller.

Something like that.

```
    if(uselogin)
    {
        var delegete = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        delegete.window?.rootViewController = newViewController
        presentViewController
    }
```

Comment: No, I would just like to move to a different view controller. Not reference the app delegate and change the root view controller.

Comment: Then I think you can use present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil);